# Loading indicator in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-circularprogressindicator, linearprogressindicator

In Flutter we have `CircularProgessIndicator` and `LinearProgessIndicator`.
I have a ListView with a couple of items and each one does a network request. Using one of the indicators does not look very appealing since you get like 8 loading indicators on the screen at times.
Youtube does it different. The items do not have neither circulator nor linear indicator. Rather you have like a gey background moving a little bit indicating that something is going on.
I hope you get what I mean. Does Flutter have such a thing?